# House of the inverse

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

Let $\alpha,\beta\in\overline{\mathbb Q}$. Denote by $h(\alpha)$ the house $\alpha$, that is the maximum of $|\sigma(\alpha)|$ when $\sigma$ describes $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$. It is easy to prove that
$$h(\alpha+\beta)\le h(\alpha)+h(\beta)\text{ and }h(\alpha\beta)\le h(\alpha)+h(\beta).$$
But I do not find an estimation of $h(\alpha/\beta)$. Does anyone know such a formula?

Comment: Are you sure of your definition of $h$ ? If $\sigma$ is in $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/ \mathbb{Q}(\alpha))$, then $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$ and $h(\alpha)$ is nothing but $\vert\alpha\vert$. And why are you tagging "transcendental numbers" ? your numbers are algebraic...

Comment: My mistake.House of algebraic numbers are used in transcendental number theory mainly.

Comment: your second inequality is doubtful...I would rather say $h(\alpha\beta)\leq h(\alpha) h(\beta).$

Comment: And it is not "the house", it is "the height" !

Comment: Waldschmidt "Diophantine approximation on linear algeraic groups:"  page 80: The house of an algebraic number is the maximum of the modulus of its
conjugates in C. And you are right my seond equality is not correct. It is $h(\alpha\beta)\le h(\alpha)h(\beta)$l.

Comment: Ok, never heard this denomination before.